# How is write PHP mcrypt_ecb decrypt in Ruby?

Tags: php, ruby, encryption, mcrypt

```
public static function decryptSessionByDES($str,$key_str){
  $decoded =base64_decode($str);
  $iv = substr($key_str, 0, mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_3DES,MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
  return trim(mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_3DES, $key_str, $decoded, MCRYPT_DECRYPT, $iv));
}
```

How to covert this code in Ruby?

Comment: it could be helpful to include example input and the expected corresponding output in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I was solved that:

here is a gem base in libmcrypt: https://github.com/kingpong/ruby-mcrypt

```
require "mcrypt"
class Crypt
  def self.decrypt_session_by_des(str, key_str)
    str_decoded = Base64.decode64(str)
    mc = Mcrypt.new(:des,:ecb)
    mc.padding = :pkcs
    mc.key = key_str
    mc.decrypt(str_decoded)
  end
end
```

and the others decrypt or encrypt you can see the test cases in ruby-mcrypt: 
https://github.com/kingpong/ruby-mcrypt/blob/master/test/test_reciprocity.rb